# Go back in time with a SQL request with a join or group by

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I'm working on an old DB and I have to create new columns based on old ones. This is a log table, each lines is an event. So `uid` is a User ID and a user can make several validation requests.

Here's my table

```
event_id  uid     event
1         1       REQUEST
2         1       VALIDATION
3         2       REQUEST
4         3       REQUEST
5         3       VALIDATION
6         2       VALIDATION
7         1       REQUEST
8         1       VALIDATION
```

Here's what I'd like to have

```
event_id  uid       event        last_event_id   request_nb     
1         1         REQUEST      8               1
2         1         VALIDATION   8               1
3         2         REQUEST      6               1
4         3         REQUEST      5               1
5         3         VALIDATION   5               1
6         2         VALIDATION   6               1
7         1         REQUEST      8               2
8         1         VALIDATION   8               2
```

I assume that I need a `group by` on `uid`, a sum like `1 + SUM(CASE WHEN EVENT = 'VALIDATION' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS request_nb`. And a `MAX` somewhere for `last_event_id`. But I'm not familiar with these kinds of join.

Here's my sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
  `event_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `docs` (`event_id`, `uid`, `event`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'REQUEST'),
  ('2', '1', 'VALIDATION'),
  ('3', '2', 'REQUEST'),
  ('4', '3', 'REQUEST'),
  ('5', '3', 'VALIDATION'),
  ('6', '2', 'VALIDATION'),
  ('7', '1', 'REQUEST'),
  ('8', '1', 'VALIDATION');
```

and fiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/404dcf/1

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT a.event_id
     , a.uid
     , a.event
     , a.i
     , b.last_event_id
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.* 
            , CASE WHEN @prev_uid = uid THEN CASE WHEN @prev_event = event THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev_uid := uid prev_uid
            , @prev_event := event prev_event FROM docs x
            , (SELECT @prev_uid := null, @prev_event := null, @i:=1) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY uid
            , event
            , event_id
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT uid, MAX(event_id) last_event_id FROM docs GROUP BY uid ) b
    ON b.uid = a.uid
  ORDER 
    BY a.event_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
And how would you make the `last_event_id` column ? 
Thanks

Comment: @RobinFourcade Come on. It ain't rocket science.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know it's not difficult to have a result but as I've quite a big table so I just wanted to have like an 'optimized' solution! So once again, thank you very much for your full answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ANSI-standard window functions:

```
select t.*,
       max(event_id) over (partition by uid) as last_event_id,
       row_number() over (partition by uid, event order by event_id) as request_nb
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, but first I've the following error : `Validation failed: Query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by uid) as last_event_id, row_number() over (partition by uid,' at line 2`
And one uid can have multiple `request_nb` (as the uid 1 in my example) is that what your request is doing ?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems that MySql doesn't handle OVER.

Comment: @RobinFourcade . . . When I answered this question, it did not have a MySQL tag.

Comment: Yes, I know, my bad, sorry about that! But thank you for your answer! :)